Do I need to submbit sitemapindex to google search console?
I have a site. Do I just sumbit sitemapindex (root sitemap) to google search console. Or, do I need to separately submit sitemap to google console?
I have limited discovered site in root sitemap.

You just need to submit the root url.  Google will find all other pages, as long as they are linked internally.  If you wish, you can submit the sitemap as well.
If you have a sitemapindex with several sitemaps, just the sitemapindex is sufficient.  But you may submit all the sitemaps if you so wish.
